# How to start same animation multiple times concurrently

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am currently working on a hit/damage animation in Flutter. I want that each time the screen is tapped, it throws an animation showing an integer. I could not find a way to make it work. For now each time I tap the screen, the animation starts over stopping the previous one. I use the BLoC pattern inside the project so this animation is thrown by a streambuilder.

Here is my current code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final StreamController<int> streamController = StreamController<int>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          streamController.sink.add(Random().nextInt(5));
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: StreamBuilder<int>(
              stream: streamController.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return DamageAnimated(snapshot.data);
                }
                return Container();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DamageAnimated extends StatefulWidget {
  const DamageAnimated(this.damage);
  final int damage;

  @override
  _DamageAnimatedState createState() => _DamageAnimatedState();
}

class _DamageAnimatedState extends State<DamageAnimated> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    animationController.forward(from: 0.0);
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(0, -100 * animationController.value),
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: 1 - animationController.value,
            child: Text(
              '${widget.damage}',
            ),
          ),j
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This displays an integer translating upward and fading away at same time but I can't figure out how to have the same animation running multiple time concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only ever returning 1 DamageAnimated. Look at the example below - you'll need to implement something similar. Btw, the ... syntax to expand a list is new in dart, so you need to update sdk version in pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"
```

I've tested this on iOS, not Android, but no reason it shouldn't work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> _anims = [];
  int _count = 0;
  int _animationsRunning = 0;

  void animationEnded() {
    _animationsRunning--;
    if (_animationsRunning == 0) {
      setState(() {
        _anims = [];
      });
      print('all animations completed - removing widget from stack (now has ${_anims.length} elements)');
    }
  }

  void _startAnimation() {
    setState(() {
      _anims.add(DamageAnimated(_count, animationEnded));
      _count++;
      _animationsRunning++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            ..._anims,
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _startAnimation,
        tooltip: 'Start animation',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DamageAnimated extends StatefulWidget {
  const DamageAnimated(this.damage, this.endedCallback);
  final int damage;
  final VoidCallback endedCallback;

  @override
  _DamageAnimatedState createState() => _DamageAnimatedState();
}

class _DamageAnimatedState extends State<DamageAnimated> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    )..addStatusListener((AnimationStatus status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed)
        if (mounted) {
          widget.endedCallback();
        }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    animationController.forward(from: 0.0);
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animationController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(0, -100 * animationController.value),
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: 1 - animationController.value,
            child: Text(
              '${widget.damage}',
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try adding StatusListeners to the animation or you could, instead, reset and start the animation each time you tap the screen such as:

```
onTap: () {
      streamController.sink.add(Random().nextInt(5));
      animationController.reset();
      animationController.forward(from: 0.0);
    },
```

I couldn't try this on my own at the moment, but I think it's a way to do it.

Sorry for waisting your time if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I see two issues with your answer, first the onTap doesn't have access to the AnimationController and even if we could share them using a bit of state management, the reset() method would start over the **same** animation, so if it had the status isAnimating, it would simply stop and restart. I'm trying to have another animation thrown, letting the previous finish but starting another one before it ends. Showing multiple integer at the same time.